# React Hook - useCustomHook to set outside useState and useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the main component along with local state using useState and useRef, I also another custom hook, inside the custom hook I would like to reset my main component's state and ref, am I doing correctly by below?

```
// custom hook
const useLoadData = ({startLoad, setStartLoad, setLoadCompleted, setUserNameRef}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
     const fetchUser = async() => { await fetchFromApi(...); return userName;};
     
     if (startLoad) {
         const newUserName = fetchUser();
         setStartLoad(false);
         setLoadCompleted(true);
         setUserNameRef(newUserName);
     }
    
  }, [startLoad]);
}
// main component
const myMainComp = () {
   const [startLoad, setStartLoad] = useState(false);
   const [loadCompleted, setLoadCompleted] = useState(false);
   const userNameRef = useRef("");
   const setUserNameRef = (username) => { this.userNameRef.current = username; }

   useLoadData(startLoad, setStartLoad, setLoadCompleted, setUserNameRef);

   refreshPage = (userId) => {
     setStartLoad(true);
   }
}
```

Am I using the custom hook correctly like by passing all external state value and setState method in? Also I found even I don't use `useEffect` in my customHook, it also works as expected, so do I need to use `useEffect` in my custom hook? Any review and suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

First, I think isn't a good approach you use component methods inside custom hook (like "set" methods provided by `useState`). You are binding the hook with the main component's internal logic. If the purpose of custom hook is fetch data from API, it need to provide to main component the vars that can be able the main component to manipulate its state by itself (like return `isFetching`, `error`, `data`, etc. and don't call any main component `set` method inside hook).

Comment: Makes sense! But how could I use my return value from custom hook to reset my main component state and ref in my case? I know that custom hook can return something, but where should I place my code to use the return value and set within my main component?

Comment: One approach I can think of like turning userNameRef into a local state in my main component, `const userName = useLoadData(startLoad)`, then make another `useEffect` in my main component to watch for this `userName`, but how could I know and set `loadCompleted`? Also I feel this kind of back and forth operation...

Comment: I think the better way in your case is don't use a custom hook and move all logic to main component. It will be easier to relate the states of the main component with the side effects of your code (api fetch) without having to keep variables both inside the hook and your main component.

Comment: But if you want to keep the hook, your approach isn't wrong... you need to sync the behaviors with a `useEffect`, eventually expose more vars and relate its content inside the useEffect, or use the hook return values itself instead of main component's state vars